# Creating a Triggers

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

How do I start a trigger so that this allows nobody to be able to rent a movie if their unpaid balance exceeds 50 dollars?

Comment: Why do you have a mysql tag if this is Oracle 10g?  Well, the first step in creating a trigger is going off and reading [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10766/tdddg_triggers.htm#TDDDG52800) .  If you google for "oracle trigger example" there a million results.  If you then have a **specific** problem, please come back and ask another question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have here is a cross-row table constraint - i.e. you can't just put a single Oracle `CONSTRAINT` on a column, as these can only look at data within a single row at a time.

Oracle has support for only two cross-row constraint types - uniqueness (e.g. primary keys and unique constraints) and referential integrity (foreign keys).

In your case, you'll have to hand-code the constraint yourself - and with that comes the responsibility to ensure that the constraint is not violated in the presence of multiple sessions, each of which cannot see data inserted/updated by other concurrent sessions (at least, until they commit).

A simplistic approach is to add a trigger that issues a query to count how many records conflict with the new record; but this won't work because the trigger cannot see rows that have been inserted/updated by other sessions but not committed yet; so the trigger will sometimes allow members to rent 6 videos, as long as (for example) they get two cashiers to enter the data in separate terminals.

**One way** to get around this problem is to put some element of serialization in - e.g. the trigger would first request a lock on the member record (e.g. with a SELECT FOR UPDATE) before it's allowed to check the rentals; that way, if a 2nd session tries to insert rentals, it will wait until the first session does a commit or rollback.

**Another way** around this problem is to use an aggregating Materialized View, which would be based on a query that is designed to find any rows that fail the test; the expectation is that the MV will be empty, and you put a table constraint on the MV such that if a row was ever to appear in the MV, the constraint would be violated. The effect of this is that any statement that tries to insert rows that violate the constraint will cause a constraint violation when the MV is refreshed.

Writing the query for this based on your design is left as an exercise for the reader :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restrict something about your table data then you should have a look at *Constraints* and not *Triggers*.

*Constraints* are ensuring some conditions about your table data. Like your example.

*Triggers* are fired when some action (i.e. INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE) took place and you can do some work then as a reaction to this action.

Comment: Note that a single Oracle table `CONSTRAINT`, on its own, will not be sufficient for this particular problem.

Comment: As far as I understand the table structure right a constraint for the *transaction* mapping table would do the trick here.

Comment: Ok @Fabian, I'd be interested to see what constraint you will propose.